# How can I change the icon displayed at the window of a HTML file?

Tags: html, icons

I want to create a HTML file.

I don't need to show the code because there's no error in the file.

So:

Who's getting tired of having the same icon displayed on a window?

I use **Google Chrome** and you might use it as well.

You might have noticed that whenever you create a file and test it, the icon on the window is a white-Earth looking thing.

So... Here's my question:

How do you change it?

```
/*
No errors in file
My question is how to change the icon?
*/
```

When you answer, please put the full code!
eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a way,

Put this after the /style tag but before the /head tag

It's in the comments now

Comment: I think this what you mean, like a lot of applications have a little icon such as google or stack overflow. It's just like a normal html pic but put in the link in a special block

Comment: Can you please put it in a full code, like putting the whole tag and telling where it should belong? is it in the ```<head``` tag or what?

Comment: <link rel = "icon" href = "Image Link" type = "image/x-icon"> 


Put this after the /style tag but before the /head tag

Comment: And make sure you have the actual image and not the wrong url

Comment: <link rel = "icon" href = "Image Link" type = "image/x-icon"> 


Put this after the /style tag but before the /head tag

Comment: also, put what before the <style> tag?